# Unable to access my contract function with web3.eth.contract

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity, truffle

```js
//Contract build .json to js obj
import { abi } from './contract.js'

//Init web3
import { getWeb3 } from  './getWeb3'

// Import are working fine.

export const getTokenContract = () => (
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getWeb3.then(web3 => { //Get web3
      var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi) //Instance contract with json abi
      var instance = contract.at("0x918daf9d0bd5c927ca8f1c5776e7c0c200be0fc23994dbe34dd9c9669c6a900d") //Get adress of the contract
      console.log(contract)
      resolve(instance)
    })
  })
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

I try to access my smart contract functions inside the instance. While I console.log, the function present in the abi are correctly display.

No functions is avalaible from the adress.
For exemple:

instance.getFidelity...

getFidelity isn't defined so crash.

- testrpc launched.
- truffle compile
- truffle migrate (success deployed at 0x918...)

Abi json:

```js
// Token Interface
export const Token = [
  {
    "contractName": "MetaCoin",
    "abi": [
      {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "addr",
            "type": "address"
          }
        ],
        "name": "getFidelity",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "owner",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "",
            "type": "address"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "receiver",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "name": "amount",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "sendCoin",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "sufficient",
            "type": "bool"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "redeemFidelity",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "sufficient",
            "type": "bool"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "newOwner",
            "type": "address"
          }
        ],
        "name": "transferOwnership",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "addr",
            "type": "address"
          }
        ],
        "name": "getBalance",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "inputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "constructor"
      },
      {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "indexed": true,
            "name": "_from",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "indexed": true,
            "name": "_to",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "indexed": false,
            "name": "_value",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "Transfer",
        "type": "event"
      },
      {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "indexed": true,
            "name": "_from",
            "type": "address"
          }
        ],
        "name": "Fidelity",
        "type": "event"
      },
      {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "indexed": true,
            "name": "previousOwner",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "indexed": true,
            "name": "newOwner",
            "type": "address"
          }
        ],
        "name": "OwnershipTransferred",
        "type": "event"
      }
    ]
    }

  ];
```

ERC20 Smart Contract

```js
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

import "./Ownable.sol";

contract MetaCoin is Ownable {

 mapping (address => uint) balances;
  mapping (address => uint) fidelity;

 event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
 event Fidelity(address indexed _from);

 function MetaCoin() {
  balances[tx.origin] = 10000;
    fidelity[tx.origin] = 100;
 }

 function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) returns(bool sufficient) {
  if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return false;
  balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
  balances[receiver] += amount;
    if (receiver == owner && amount > 10) {
      fidelity[msg.sender] += 1;
    }
    Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
  return true;
 }

 function redeemFidelity() returns (bool sufficient) {
  if (fidelity[msg.sender] < 10) return false;
  fidelity[msg.sender] -= 10;
  Fidelity(msg.sender);
  return true;
 }

 function getBalance(address addr) returns(uint) {
  return balances[addr];
 }

  function getFidelity(address addr) returns(uint) {
  return fidelity[addr];
 }

}
```

Comment: And what is the content of `./getWeb3`  file ?

Comment: getWeb3 just do a promise and some check for metamask. It's working fine I can use it for any other function with web3

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI https://gist.github.com/DealSegfault/9eff3358b09d6953406b2991a3ead78f